# java bean null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ejb

This is my first post, so hopefully I live up to the high standards of the community.

I'm trying to learn Enterprise Java beans and I've been thrown into the deep end and asked to debug an EAR file that's throwing a `NullPointerException`. This is the line that's throwing the Exception:

```
private CrashMonitorTimer crash;
...
/*THE NEXT LINE THROWS THE NULL POINTER EXCEPTION*/
crash.createTimer(Long.parseLong(sCrashMonitorInterval),"CrashMoniterScheduler");
```

This is the code for the interface being called:

```
import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface CrashMonitorTimer
{
    public abstract void createTimer(long l, String s);

    public abstract void cancelTimer(String s);
}
```

And this is the code for the Java bean:

```
@Stateless(name = "CrashMonitorBean", mappedName = "CrashMonitorBean")
@Local(CrashMonitorTimer.class)

public class CrashMonitorBean
    implements CrashMonitorTimer
{

    @Resource
    SessionContext sessionCtx;
    TimerService timerService;
    Timer timer;
    int iMsgCntBeforeCtxRenew;
    int iCtxReusedCount;
    Context _context;
    CrashMonitorInfoUtil crashMonitorRMIContext[];

    public CrashMonitorBean()
    {
        iMsgCntBeforeCtxRenew = 10;
        iCtxReusedCount = 0;
        _context = null;
        crashMonitorRMIContext = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void createTimer(long lInterval, String sName)
    {

        //CrashMonitorInfoUtil leaves context open for reuse 

        System.out.println((new StringBuilder("Creating ")).append(sName).append(" timer").toString());
        timerService = sessionCtx.getTimerService();
        timer = timerService.createTimer(lInterval, lInterval, sName);
        String sPorts = SystemConfigurator.getConfigValue("RMIPorts");
        String saPorts[] = sPorts.split(",");
        String server = SystemConfigurator.getConfigValue("host");
        crashMonitorRMIContext = new CrashMonitorInfoUtil[saPorts.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < saPorts.length; i++)
        {
            crashMonitorRMIContext[i] = new CrashMonitorInfoUtil(server, saPorts[i]);
        }

    }
...
}
```

I've poked around at this, but having had zero experience with Java beans or interfaces (or the new annotations) I'm kind of at a loss on what I should even try. Any explanation or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the exception stack trace. I can see many places where you could have a NPE and the stack trace would show the correct one.

Comment: The problem may be: `crash` variable is not being injected, `sCrashMonitorInterval` has `null` value.

Comment: `crash` variable is null. @LuiggiMendoza if `sCrashMonitorInterval` were `null`, then it would have thrown `java.lang.NumberFormatException` and not `NullPointerException`

Comment: @YatendraGoel well, the problem seems to be the injection of the EJB. OP: please add more info about the class definition that has this `private CrashMonitorTimer crash;` field.

Comment: @BrandonToms How are you initializing/injecting the `crash` bean?

Comment: A coworker and I determined that crash is INDEED not being instantiated.  This is the first I've heard of injection, so I'll have some studying to do when I get home.  I threw a `crash = new CrashMonitorBean();` in there and that seems to have fixed that NPE.  Another one popped up further down the line, which I will try to address myself.

Thank you so much, folks.  I love this community, hopefully I'll be able to contribute answers of my own someday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crash` variable is `null`.

If `sCrashMonitorInterval` were null, then it would have thrown `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Then `crash` is not being injected. IMO this is still not enough info to solve the problem.